# Windows Service (TCP Client/Listener) Firewall Exception Blocks Traffic

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-services, windows-firewall

I have a `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` based Windows Service running on two machines on my network.  Both client and server nodes operate from the same Windows service.  The service runs as `Local System` and `PC01` is Win7 x64 and `PC02` is Win7 x86.

The application was throwing a `SocketException` 10060 (connection timed out) during connection attempts from client to server, and I have found that the Windows firewall exceptions generated by the application's automatic firewall configuration code are not allowing TCP traffic to pass through.

Taking a step back, I tried the following tests sequentially on `PC01` with the firewall on `PC02` permanently disabled to remove it as a variable:

1. Disabled the firewall on `PC01` - this worked.
2. Enabled the firewall on `PC01` and *manually* added an exception to allow all inbound `TCP` traffic on port `12345` - this worked.
3. Further restricted the exception to allow remote traffic from the local subnet only - this worked.
4. Further restricted the exception to allow (all) services only - this worked.
5. Further restricted the exception to allow the specific service by selecting from the list of services or by entering service short name - this **failed.**
6. Attempted instead to restrict the exception to the specific service by selecting the `myservice.exe` executable - this **failed.**

What is it about my Windows service that prevents this from working when the exception is restricted to the specific service? Is there a caveat for Windows services that I should be aware of?  Is opening the port for all services the only solution?

---

EDIT: I've used `netstat -a -n -b` to collect info regarding active connections and listening ports.  The below excerpt details the information regarding my service:

```
Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:12345          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[myservice.exe]
...
UDP    0.0.0.0:12344          *:*                    
[myservice.exe] (listening for UDP broadcast packets)
...
UDP    0.0.0.0:62794          *:*                    
[myservice.exe] (this is an outbound broadcast packet)
```

Thanks everyone for any insights you can offer.

Comment: I've posted this on SO instead of SF because I think it must have something to do with my specific service.

Comment: You can use `netstat -a -n -b` to see listening ports and the associated executables; is it your executable that is listening on port 12345?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you for that - yes, my executable appears in the list of active connections, both on the expected TCP port and on a UDP port I also have open.  I'll add the info to the question.

Comment: Perhaps you need to remove the "services only" option in order to select an executable?  That is, the two options might be mutually exclusive?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well... have selected the `myservice.exe` executable and the service option for All Programs and Services.  Same result, inbound traffic on the port is still blocked.  Thanks Harry.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to make certain that you're pointing the firewall to the same copy of `myservice.exe` that is actually running.  You should also make sure the path is in the same format, if one uses short filenames and the other uses long filenames it might not work.  (Actually it might not work if either uses short filenames, I wouldn't be surprised.)  I think Process Explorer (available from the MS web site) can help you there.

Comment: Bingo!  That was it - it was the format of the path.  I opened `regedit` and found the path for the service was `C:\Users\Person\Documents\Source\Repos\repo\software\version\bin\Debug\myservice.exe` however when I selected it through the firewall dialog the path became `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Source\Repos\repo\software\version\bin\Debug\myservice.exe`.  This must be the reason the service list selection doesn't work, it probably converts the selection to the second path.  Thank you!!  Please create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for selecting a specific executable to work, the path to the executable must match the path the firewall is expecting.  Apparently the firewall GUI for some reason was converting the path so that is was relative to `%USERPROFILE%` ; I suspect this constitutes a bug in Windows.

(If I remember correctly, the firewall can in general cope with paths that use environment variables, e.g., `%SystemRoot%`, but obviously a per-user environment variable won't work, since the firewall rules are not evaluated in the correct user's context.)

Comment: I'm adding the firewall exception programmatically, so I will simply determine the path to the service at run time and use this instead of the service short name.  Thanks Harry!

Comment: After further testing, it turned out that for a service run as `Local System` that `%USERPROFILE%` evaluated to `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService`.